# Tekton Migrating From paketobuildpacks/builder:base To paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base

Tags: tekton, tekton-pipelines

The Tekton pipeline was working fine until the migration to Jammy.  The only pipeline code changed was the image builder name.

1. On the "**buildpacks**" (https://hub.tekton.dev/tekton/task/buildpacks) task the "**prepare**" step works fine and I can see the permissions being applied:

```
> Setting permissions on '/workspace/cache'...
> Setting permissions on '/tekton/home'...
> Setting permissions on '/layers'...
> Setting permissions on '/workspace/source'...
> Parsing additional configuration...
-> Parsing env variables...
> Processing any environment variables...
--> Creating 'env' directory: /platform/env
--> Writing /platform/env/BP_NATIVE_IMAGE...
--> Writing /platform/env/BP_JVM_VERSION...
--> Writing /platform/env/BP_GRADLE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS...
--> Writing /platform/env/BP_GRADLE_BUILT_ARTIFACT...
--> Writing /platform/env/REPOSITORY_NAME...
--> Writing /platform/env/REPOSITORY_URL...
--> Writing /platform/env/REPOSITORY_USERNAME...
--> Writing /platform/env/REPOSITORY_PASSWORD...
```

2. Then the second task "**create**" fails with the error below:

```
2024/02/10 19:44:47 warning: unsuccessful cred copy: ".docker" from "/tekton/creds" to "/": unable to create destination directory: mkdir /.docker: permission denied

ERROR: failed to set environment for user 1000: user: unknown userid 1000
```

Comment: In my research I found that the Jammy buildpack uses two users, 1000 to setup the environment and 1001 to perform the image build. So, I changed the Tekton pipeline, but I'm keep getting the error below. Please, could someone tell me what is missing in my Pipeline script?.............warning: unsuccessful cred copy: ".docker" from "/tekton/creds" to "/": unable to create destination directory: mkdir /.docker: permission denied.............ERROR: failed to exec as user 1001:1000: operation not permitted